# Switch statement fallthrough

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am working on a raytracer and I am trying to implement sampling. Now I have an enum that represents the sampling type, let's call them 'One', 'Two', 'Three' for simplicity. Now 'One' and 'Two' are independant of each other but if something needs sampling of type 'Three' then the code for both 'One' and 'Two' needs to run. Right now I am doing this:

```
bool flag = false;
switch(type) {
case Three: flag = true;
case One: 
// ...
if(!flag) break;
case Two:
// ...
break;
}
```

Is there a 'sneaky' way of doing it without the boolean? I could think of putting the code for 'One' and 'Two' into seperate functions and call both in case of 'Three' but I don't want function calls there, as this gets called >a lot<. Inlining the functions would be another option but that'd result in duplicated code.

Comment: also if you can think of a better name for this question, feel free to edit it ( I couldn't )

Comment: `if (type==One || type==Three) { ... } if (type==Two || type==Three) { ... } ` would be a possibility.

Comment: Why not just `if (type == one || type == three) { ... } if (type == two || type == three)  { ... }`?

Comment: switch statement is good when the cases naturally execute in order (or always break), if thats not the case, then simply dont use a switch statement. Imho the flag is rather hacky

Comment: i like it complicated @NathanOliver, no I was too focused on the already implemented switch that I completely overlooked this option xD

Comment: "i like it complicated" Your readers won't (and you won't when you have to fix bugs), and neither will people you're asking for free help ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 yes that was a joke, I was too focused on making it work as a switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was too focused on trying to make it work as a switch but as @NathanOliver pointed out it's as easy as

```
if(type==One || type == Three) {
// case One
}
if(type==Two || type == Three) {
// case Two
}
```

Comment: Why not introduce some simple booleans matching these conditions? Give them nice names that describe what those conditions mean. Then it's just two, easy-to-read `if` statements.

Comment: yes, now we get into readability, that wasn't the point of the question but of course entirely possibly

Comment: It strikes me that readability is the entire and complete point of the question

Comment: it was intended more as an optimization related question, but that might have missed the point